# Constructing a mapping between cartesian plane and torus.

Tags: general-topology

Given Cartesian coordinates, $(x, y)$, I am looking to transform them into $(x, y, z)$ coordinates on a torus centered at the origin of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the major and minor radii given.

If any more clarification is needed, feel free to ask.

Thank you very much.

Comment: think about a circle going around another circle. what is (x,y)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A torus embedded the way you want can be written as the set of all points of the form $v_{\theta} + w_{\phi}$ where $v_{\theta}$ traces out the "major circle" and $w_{\phi}$ traces out the "minor circle." If we put the major circle in the $xy$-plane then we can take $v_{\theta} = (R \cos \theta, R \sin \theta, 0)$. The minor circle is a bit trickier because its orientation changes with $v_{\theta}$: it lies in the $\{ z, v_{\theta} \}$-plane, which means we can take

$$w_{\phi} = (r \cos \phi) \frac{v_{\theta}}{|v_{\theta}|} + (0, 0, r \sin \phi) = (r \cos \theta \cos \phi, r \sin \theta \cos \phi, r \sin \phi).$$

Altogether this gives

$$v_{\theta} + w_{\phi} = \left( \cos \theta (R + r \cos \phi), \sin \theta (R + r \cos \phi), r \sin \phi \right)$$

which agrees, for example, with the formulas on [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html). [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/thinking-about-multivariable-function/ways-to-represent-multivariable-functions/a/parametric-functions-two-parameters) has some nice visualizations:

[image]